# Performances spikes on Node.js application using LoopBack and Kerberos

Tags: node.js, performance, docker, kerberos, loopbackjs

Our API's implemented with Node.js using the LoopBack framework retrieving data from HBase using Kerberos as authentication layer show inexplicable performance spikes of 5000 ms and 10000 ms with the bulk of the requests returning a result within 1000 ms.

[performance spikes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCW4H.png)

Our applications are running as a Docker container on OpenShift.
We are running Node.js version 6.13 and our OS is Red Hat Linux 7.3

We tried pinpointing the issue performing the following actions:

1. Run with and without Kerberos.
   Although running the application with Kerberos seems to worsen the spikes running the application without Kerberos shows more or less the same patterns.
   Therefore we ruled out Kerberos as the source of the problem.
2. Run the application locally instead of in OpenShift.
   The spikes occur both locally as in OpenShift.
   Therefore we ruled out OpenShift as the source of the problem.
3. Create the application with and without LoopBack.
   The spikes occur on both applications and therefore we also ruled out LoopBack as the source of the problem.
4. Using Node.js (with LoopBack) with an in-memory database.
   When using an in-memory database and not performing any external requests we don't see spikes anymore.
   From this we concluded that Node.js itself is not the problem but something seems to be going on using the Node.js external requests.

We are looking for suggestions what might cause our performance issues or where we could investigate further.

Comment: Do those memory spikes happen in production? Could it be that those slow requests are caused by people on slow internet connections or that are far away from your server?

Comment: That looks like a DNS issue. If your primary [resolver](https://linux.die.net/man/5/resolv.conf) times out after 5 seconds, then it moves onto the second resolver. Occasionally the second times out and you get 10s. Can you try using IP's for your hbase connections, or whatever other host names your API looks up? Another option could be to test a local caching forwarding server like [unbound](https://unbound.net/). What OS are you on?

Comment: Spikes do happen in production. We see the spikes on our own test runs (JMeter) on the local network so no impact of slow internet connection.

Comment: We also tried using static IP's which shows the same performance impact. Next to that added OS (RedHat 7.3)  to original question.

Comment: Do you get the same delay against a standalone HBase node? Is there any commonality between the requests taking 5/10s? Are they succesful responses?

Comment: Spike request are succesful and there seems to be no commonality between those request. We did not test against a standalone HBase node but we see the same pattern if we test against other data sources.

Comment: Unless there is another library in your app that has a 5s timeout and retry logic, I'd look at DNS some more. Maybe trace the lookups  occurring between a run exhibiting and and compare against an in memory database run.

Answer (score 0):

We have solved this issue, it did turn out to be the way NodeJS handles DNS lookup requests.

At first we did not believe this could be the case, no other application had connectivity issues and launching the same requests using curl resulted in no time-out’s. After using systrace we noticed that one out of every 100 DNS lookup requests took an awful long time, coinciding with the spikes we saw earlier. After adding the IP addresses to the hosts file on each machine running our Node code the issue was resolved.